# Getting getElementByID from localStorage

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to `getElementById` from keys stored in `localStorage`. What I have is the following data in my localStorage:

> question1 = Answer1
>
> question2 = Answer2 etc.

And script:

```
<script>
if (localStorage.getItem("question1") === null) {
} else {
    document.getElementById('question1').innerHTML = (localStorage.getItem("question1"));
}

if (localStorage.getItem("question2") === null) {
} else {
    document.getElementById('question2').innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("question2");
}
</script>
```

But what I'd like to have is that it will place the value of each key stored in localStorage in their ElementById with the same name as the key.

```
for (x in localStorage){
    document.getElementById(x).innerHTML = localStorage.getItem(x);
}
```

Comment: you must save it as json array to localstorage using JSON.stringify, and then when you read 1 time from localstorage, then do a JSON.parse to get your list of objects back. Then you can iterate over them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `spread` operator to do as

```
const items = { ...localStorage };

for (x in items){
    document.getElementById(x).innerHTML = localStorage.getItem(x);
}
```

Comment: Amazing, how simple. I didn't know about this. Works very good! Thank you very much!

Comment: Done! I'm sorry, I'm a newbie.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```js
let i = 1;
const item =  localStorage.getItem("question"+i)
while(item){
    document.getElementById(x).innerHTML = item
    i+=1;
    const item =  localStorage.getItem("question"+i)
}
```

**Note:**

```
const items = { ...localStorage };
```

May iterate **non question** items